# why carbon::now() does not work on observer or job in host (laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, observers

I set a field of type `timestamp` with `carbon::now()`, but field get null value!

in the job (`handle()` method) or observer (`created()` method) :

```
$cart->publish_date = Carbon::now();
$cart->save();
```

but in the localhost everything is ok !

what is wrong ?

thanks

Comment: You can try to only use `now()` instead of `Carbon\Carbon::now()`. They are the same. Maybe it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

`Carbon::now();` returns an object of Carbon.
If you need to save it to a database column you must do:

```
$cart->publish_date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$cart->save();
```

Comment: It still remains null

Comment: It shouldn't.. Can you post the whole code please?

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try.

```php
$cart->update(['publish_date' => now()]);
```

This reads a bit cleaner IMO and removes the need for the Carbon import (If Carbon isn't being used anywhere else in the class)